# how to map product and category urls for same url patterns

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to customize category and product urls like examples below. But in my case category and product urls has same pattern so handling with @RequestMapping become impossible. is there any out-of-box solution for this kind of customization or what is the best practice.

`default category url: /Tools/Hammers/c/1356`

`custom url for category: /Hammers`

`default product url: /Power-Drills/Hammer-drill-6900/p/3887529,`

`custom url for product: /Hammer-drill-6900`

Answer (score 1):

As i know there is no out of the box solution provided by **Hybris** to reach this, however you can make use of the **Spring Web Filters** to catch the `HttpServletRequest` and check if the `request.getServletPath()` is a **Category** or then **forward** to the `Category controller` if it's of type product then **forward** to the `Product Controller`.

The following code snippet may help you :

```
public class ControllerForwardFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    public CategoryService categoryService;
    @Autowired
    public ProductService productService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //get servletPath
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath();

        //Assuming that categoryService.findByName(categoryName) exist
        CategoryModel category = categoryService.findByName(servletPath);
        if(category != null) {
            String forwardUrl = "/c/" + category.getCode();
            request.getRequestDispatcher(forwardUrl).forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        //Assuming that productService.findByName(productName) exist
        ProductModel product = productService.findByName(servletPath);
        if(product != null) {
            String forwardUrl = "/p/" + product.getCode();
            request.getRequestDispatcher(forwardUrl).forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        //otherwise it's a Home page or Account page continue
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

You will need just to remove the redirect from CategoryController and ProductController.

Comment: Hi Mouad, thanks for your reply. i was think about a solution like this but there are some other cases like url changes. i will need to handle 301 redirect from old one to new one. May be there is a open source library and i wont need to implement from beginning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Deep Linking?

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Deep+Linking+-+Technical+Guide